# Creating a django rest framework ViewSet that has two levels of parent tabless

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have the following models for a course catalog:

- Department
- Course
- CourseInstance
- CourseInstanceTime

A `CourseInstance` is a running of a "course" which is an entry in the course catalog. Each course has a foreign key to the `Department` it belongs to. Each time in a week a course meets is stored in `CourseInstanceTime`. Simplified models below:

```py
class Department(models.Model):
    """Academic Department"""

    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

class Course(models.Model):
    """Courses in the course catalog"""

    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    course_number = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=0, max_digits=3, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("department", "course_number"),)

class CourseInstance(models.Model):
    """A Scheduled running of a particular coursee"""

    start_date = models.DateField(help_text='Course Start Date', verbose_name='Start Date')
    end_date = models.DateField(help_text='Course Start Date', verbose_name='Start Date')
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.deletion.CASCADE)

class CourseInstanceTime(models.Model):

    day = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()
    course_instance = models.ForeignKey(CourseInstance, on_delete=models.deletion.CASCADE)
```

I'd like to create a viewset of `CourseInstance` that includes the department name. I can use a `SlugField` to include the course number like so:

class CourseInstanceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    course = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        many = False,
        read_only = False,
        slug_field = 'course_number',
        queryset = models.Course.objects.all()
    )

```
class Meta:
    model = models.Course
    fields = (
        'id', 
        #'department',
        'course', 
        'start_date',
        'end_date',
    )
```

I'm at a loss for how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `source` argument to your serializer fields, so for instance, if you want to add a `department_name` to your `CourseInstanceSerializer`, you could achieve that by adding the field `department_name = serializers.CharField(source='course.department.name')`, or if you want to have the department information you could use `department = DepartmentSerializer(source='course.department')`.

Comment: Ok, it looks like I need to override create() on the serializer and viewset to get posts working the way I want, but this is worked for reads.